# echo term name outside the loop, using term slug

Tags: taxonomy, terms

I have a strange question...

I have my term as a variable...

```
$mailer = 'may-2012-newsletter';
```

And I'm trying to echo on my page the Name of my term, using the variable above. But this is not in a loop.

My term name is: **May 2012 Newsletter**

But I'm trying to echo this from using my term slug: **may-2012-newsletter**

This term is grouped in my taxonomy called: **mailers**

I've tried this below but this doesn't work? I think I'm totally off track.

```
<title><?php echo get_term_by( 'name', $mailer, 'mailers'); ?></title>
```

Any help would be awesome thanks.

Josh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [get_term_by](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_term_by) to get the term object if you know the slug and then just echo out the name ex:

```
$by = 'slug';
$slug = 'may-2012-newsletter';
$taxonomy = 'mailers';
$term = get_term_by( $by, $slug, $taxonomy);
echo $term->name;
```